# How to create lots of instances of same form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a single form and I need to duplicate it 200 times so they all together will do the processing. My form is simply taking screenshots of websites and i want to clone it many times to get a faster result. Is it possible or what is the best way for it? Should I keep on searching duplicating a form or should I find a way to open the exe file 200 times?

Comment: 200 forms?! Better refactor your code so your application logic is not part of the form...

Comment: Sounds like he is taking screenshots of a `WebControl` so I can understand the need for multiple forms. The issue is going to be if the rendering of pages is asynchronous or not.

Comment: Just curious - you do realise that running 200 of the same process at a time instead of one doesn't make it 200 times faster, right?

Comment: In fact, it makes it faster but not 200 times. This works great on getting data from web but when it comes to screenshots it conflicts because of webbrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code uses the `WebBrowser` control to open pages and then grab a screenshot (as I assume you do), I'd recommend just opening your .exe so many times and then running the instances in parallel. This at least gives you a separate process for each browser control so all those instances will only compete for network resources but the rest will be in separate processes.

Running 200 instances is almost guaranteed to be a bad idea - 200 forms with controls will use a lot of system resources. Unless you have a very powerful computer you'll have issues. Running around 50 instances will likely be better (you may have to experiment to find a sweet spot - it may be more than 50, I'm just guesstimating).

It's not an elegant solution by any means but I assume this is for a utility, not for end users.

Comment: My servers can handle it and program doesnt use much ram or cpu, but yes i use web browser and when i start multiple exe files they still seem to be conflict and cannot capture screenshot. This not for end users, just to update files on server.

Comment: @Kuzgun I'd most definitely not do processing like this on the actual server - it'll hog a lot of resources even if your server is powerful. If you use the WebBrowser control, it uses a lot of memory (just one instance). What do you mean by the different executables conflicting? When you take a screenshot, how do you do that? You should be able to have your windows each render to a memory bitmap and then save that to disk. There shouldn't be any conflict.

Comment: I don't know actually but have a guess, web browsers don't get along with threads maybe they work in same way. It doesn't sound logical but it conflicts anyway. It doesnt take lots of resources but %100 CPU usage, now programs run for 1 month i guess and do what I want, but i can run max 3 programs on each server because of CPU usage. Some of screenshots get conflict and cannot be saved while writing to disk, which I find strange because that is Windows's job.

Answer (score 1):

I would create another project which is nothing more than a loop which kicks off 200 instances of this process.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
     Process.Start(@"C:\path\to\webcrawler.exe");
```

If you need to pass some data into it make is so webcrawler accepts some command line parameters and start a command line process passing it "webcrawler.exe args" instead.